# Selected DropDown item is not Showing in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

My dropdown working fine, but selecting item is not showing up
I tried with `value: _val`   after `return DropdownButton<Partner>(` It showing error like
`Undefined name '_val'`

I also tried with declaring in class label

`class _MultipleTestBookingState extends State<MultipleTestBooking> {`

`String _val = '';`

Then its showing  error like `The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Partner?'`

```
   Container(
                  child: FutureBuilder<List<Partner>>(
                    future: AllPathLab(),
                    builder:
                        (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState !=ConnectionState.done) {
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text("Somthing went wrong");
                      }

                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return DropdownButton<Partner>(
                          value: _val , // showing error "Undefined name _val"
                          hint: Text("Select Lab"),
                    items: snapshot.data.map((Partner data) =>
                    DropdownMenuItem<Partner>(
                                              child: Text("${data.partnerName}"),
                                              value: data,
                                            )
                                            ).toList().cast<DropdownMenuItem<Partner>>(),
                      onChanged: (value){
                        setState(() {
                          _val=value; // showing error "Undefined name _val"
                          encLabId = value!.encPartnerId;
                          GetTestByLab(); 
                        });
                        

                      });
                          
                        }
                      return Text("Waiting for Internet Connection");
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there's a few things going on here...

1. You definitely do need to declare `_val` within your class if you're hoping to call `setState()` on it. But...
2. The problem with stating `String _val = '';` is that you're not using `_val` as a string. You're using it as a Partner. Your dropdown menu takes in a list of Partners (and that value you're passing in has to equal one of those), and when you select a partner, Flutter is attempting to set `_val` to the Partner you picked, and it's having trouble doing that when it's already declared as a String
3. So you should either initialize `_val` as a Partner, or make it a nullable Partner object. (i.e. something like `Partner? _val`). One nice thing about doing the latter is if it's set to null, your dropdown list can nicely handle that case and display a hint widget instead, which is probably some text that says something like, "Please select a partner."
4. Also, I'd recommend giving `_val` a more descriptive variable name. `_selectedPartner` will work so much better than `_val` when you revisit this code 6 months later. :)

Comment: Not showing any error but my app crashes with the error `There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Instance of 'Partner'. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value`

Comment: I search little bit, some of them suggesting initialized with some default value.. But again as You mentioned `_val` using it as a Partner not string

Comment: I also prefer  it's set to null...although why it getting crashed?